# How to set maximum spending on azure account

Tags: azure

I need your help to understand how I can set a maximum budget limit on my azure account. For example, let's say I don't want to spend more than 200 dollar per month how can I set that?

Comment: contact the vendor support

Answer (score 1):

Check out these documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/spending-limit#turn-on-the-spending-limit-after-removing

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/cost-management-budget-scenario

Spending limits aren't really a thing for most use cases of Azure. You're really going to want to focus on Cost Alerts and Budgets in Azure. You can have automations respond to events that occur in Budgets and Cost Alerts.

Answer (score 0):

You can set budgets using Azure cost management, however these budgets do not enforce spending limits, just let you know when you are getting close or have breached them. However, you can trigger events based on these messages, so you could use this to turn of resources when reaching a limit or similar. See [here](https://samcogan.com/enforce-budgets-with-cost-management-and-logic-apps/) for an example.